# pbs_server failed to start

Tags: linux, permissions, torque

I am following along with [the torque installation guide](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/6-0-1/Content/topics/hpcSuiteInstall/manual/1-installing/installingTorque.htm#install) and have a minor deviation: my installation is inside `/apps/torque/6.0.1` where `/apps` is a symlink from `/disk2/apps`. I am trying to run `./torque.setup drjrm3` but get the following:

```
initializing TORQUE (admin: drjrm3@jarvis)

You have selected to start pbs_server in create mode.
If the server database exists it will be overwritten.
do you wish to continue y/(n)?y
ERROR: pbs_server failed to start, check syslog and server logs for more information
```

Upon checking `/apps/torque/6.0.1/serverHome/server_logs` I see

```
07/24/2016 14:50:42.802;02;PBS_Server.1120;Svr;Log;Log opened
07/24/2016 14:50:42.802;06;PBS_Server.1120;Svr;PBS_Server;Server jarvis started, initialization type = 4
07/24/2016 14:50:42.803;01;PBS_Server.1120;Svr;PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::Operation not permitted (1) in chk_file_sec, Security violation with "/apps/torque/6.0.1/serverHome/server_priv/queues/" - /apps/torque/6.0.1/serverHome/server_priv/queues/ is not owned by admin user
07/24/2016 14:50:42.803;01;PBS_Server.1120;Svr;PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::Operation not permitted (1) in chk_file_sec, Security violation with "/apps/torque/6.0.1/serverHome/spool/" - /apps/torque/6.0.1/serverHome/spool/ is not owned by admin user
07/24/2016 14:50:42.803;01;PBS_Server.1120;Svr;PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::Operation not permitted (1) in chk_file_sec, Security violation with "/apps/torque/6.0.1/serverHome/server_priv/accounting/" - /apps/torque/6.0.1/serverHome/server_priv/accounting/ is not owned by admin user
07/24/2016 14:50:42.803;01;PBS_Server.1120;Svr;PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::Operation not permitted (1) in chk_file_sec, Security violation with "/apps/torque/6.0.1/serverHome/server_priv/credentials/" - /apps/torque/6.0.1/serverHome/server_priv/credentials/ is not owned by admin user
07/24/2016 14:50:42.803;01;PBS_Server.1120;Svr;PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::Operation not permitted (1) in chk_file_sec, Security violation with "/disk2" - /disk2 is not owned by admin user
07/24/2016 14:50:42.803;01;PBS_Server.1120;Svr;PBS_Server;LOG_ERROR::PBS_Server, pbsd_init failed
```

but this makes no sense as this user is owner of these directories. I even tried to `chmod 755` some of the directories and still got not change on these errors.

Why is my initialization of `pbs_server` failing and how can I fix this?